# AWS ECS Cluster Please configure a container with elb

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-application-load-balancer

I have created a cluster, task definition and load balancer now I am creating a service on Ecs cluster but its showing this error

[image]

My Docker file in image is

```
FROM node:alpine 
# Set the working directory to /app inside the container
# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install app dependencies
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm i 

# add app
COPY . ./
EXPOSE 8080

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Answer (score 5):

Before clicking **Next** at the bottom of the page you have to click **Add to Load Balancer** button on the right and add more details:

[image]

After you click the button new fields appear:

[image]

Review/edit the new fields and then click **Next** to proceed to the next step.